# Migrating file server with Windows Deduplication by switching disk

Tags: windows, migration, file-sharing, deduplication

I'm migrating a bunch of large file servers to new Windows VMs as a way of updating the OS, planning on switching the virtual disks over and exporting/importing the lanman share registry and retaining the same name/ip so we don't have to re-config user's mappings. Windows Deduplication is being used and I've not done this approach before on deduped volumes. If I install deduplication on the target VM before migrating, will there be any issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer elsewhere but popping it here in case it can help someone else.

Found here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/introduction-to-data-deduplication-in-windows-server-2012/ba-p/424257

3. Portability: A volume that is under deduplication control is an atomic unit. You can back up the volume and restore it to another server. You can rip it out of one Windows 2012 server and move it to another. Everything that is required to access your data is located on the drive. All of the deduplication settings are maintained on the volume and will be picked up by the deduplication filter when the volume is mounted. The only thing that is not retained on the volume are the schedule settings that are part of the task-scheduler engine. If you move the volume to a server that is not running the Data Deduplication feature, you will only be able to access the files that have not been deduplicated.

So, looks like as long as I install the dedupe feature and then re-create the schedule, I shouldn't experience any issues.